# Remove spacing on top and bottom of button

Tags: html, css, button, grid

I have a button that is inside of a column in my html.

```
  <div class="col center-items btn-row">
    <button class="button-text-big-class btn" type="button">
      Hello World
    </button>
  </div>
```

There is spacing on the top and bottom of the button (not padding, this seems to be part of the button element) that should be removed.

[image]

How can I remove the spacing on the top and bottom of the `Hello World` text--without changing the element type or removing any of my imported css classes--so it looks more like:

[image]

Note: This is not a padding issue. I have tried removing padding

```
.btn {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

But this doesn't do anything. There is spacing in the button element itself between the text in the button and the top and bottom of the button element. I have also inspected the element and verified that none of the css is adding padding.

Here is the rendered css for reference:

```
.btn {
    color: #0276b1;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;

}

.button-text-big-class {
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Optimist, "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.center-items {
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-row {
   padding-top: 56px;
   padding-bottom: 72px;
}

// col is equivalent to bootstrap's column
```

Comment: Please add a [repro] for debugging details. Also add tags with frameworks you are using if you sue frameworks such as bootstrap.

Comment: proberly just have to simply remove the padding for top and bottom of the button: `.btn { padding: 0 auto; }`

Comment: >without changing the element type or removing any of my imported css classes Maybe try digging in those "imported CSS classes" and find the padding settings there.
Those might be overriding any changes you are trying to implement outside.

Comment: `Note: This is not a padding issue. I have tried removing padding`

Comment: Can you show what code is inside this -> class="button-text-big-class btn" and this -> class="col center-items btn-row"

Answer (score 0):

The spacing has to do with the padding element, please see my example where I have two buttons with different padding and how it affects each:

```css
.btn {
padding: 0;
}
.button2 {
padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col center-items btn-row">
    <button class="button-text-big-class btn" type="button">
      Hello World
    </button>
    <button class="button2" type="button">
      Hello World
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: your snippet doesnt work correctly because you have a typo in your CSS: `button2` instead of `.button2`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, error fixed.